# Modify python string with contain method

Tags: python-2.7

I want it to find the following file in mylist: "Microsoft Word 105Prt" (this file name could vary but will always have "Word" in it.

```
for myfile in filelist:
    if myfile.contains("Word"): 
        print myfile
```

How can I modify this to work in python 2.7.5 since contains doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `in` keyword, like so:

```
if 'Word' in myfile:
    print myfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute find for contains and just check for a return code of something other than -1.

```
for myfile in filelist:
    if myfile.find("Word")!=-1: 
        print myfile
```